# smooth.spline in glm with NAs in dataset

Tags: r, glm, spline

I am trying to use a `smooth.spline` transformation for my explanatory variables in `glm` (logit regression). 
I get the error because `smooth.spline` cannot work with NAs.

Here is my code:

```
LogitModel <- glm(dummy~ smooth.spline(A) + B + C
                          ,family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = mydata)
```

How can I handle that (without changing mydata?)

Comment: I do get an error : `Error in smooth.spline(mydata$A) : 
  missing or infinite values in inputs are not allowed`

Comment: Ok I get it. I replaced all NAs with zeros. The spline gives me a list for each observation.

Comment: I think I can get predicted values from bs() and then use it in my model. I need it to transform my explanatory data.

Comment: could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 1):

You can use generalized additive models (GAM) which include splines naturally. For example, you can use `gam` package, as a side-effect they are handling `NA`'s. Please see the code below:

```
library(gam)
set.seed(123)
data(kyphosis)

# simulation of NA
NAs <- matrix(c(sample(81, 4), 1:4), byrow = FALSE, ncol = 2)
kyphosis_NA[NAs] <- NA

# gam
m_NA <- gam(Kyphosis ~ s(Age,4) + Number + Start, family = binomial, data=kyphosis_NA)
summary(m_NA)
```

Output:

```
Call: gam(formula = Kyphosis ~ s(Age, 4) + Number + Start, family = binomial, 
    data = kyphosis)
Deviance Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.21622 -0.50581 -0.24260 -0.06758  2.36573 

(Dispersion Parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null Deviance: 83.2345 on 80 degrees of freedom
Residual Deviance: 53.452 on 74 degrees of freedom
AIC: 67.452 

Number of Local Scoring Iterations: 9 

Anova for Parametric Effects
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)   
s(Age, 4)  1  0.037  0.0368  0.0442 0.834140   
Number     1  4.682  4.6816  5.6109 0.020460 * 
Start      1  8.869  8.8694 10.6301 0.001683 **
Residuals 74 61.743  0.8344                    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Anova for Nonparametric Effects
            Npar Df Npar Chisq P(Chi)
(Intercept)                          
s(Age, 4)         3     5.8327   0.12
Number                               
Start
```